SCSS Styling on wordpress site not being accepted
I can't seem to get the styling I want to add to this scss file to have output, and none of it is showing while inspecting the site even if adding in !important tag.
Here's the gist of the html:
<div class="o-faq-accordian">
            <details id="what-is-a-blank" class="o-faq-accordian__details">
            <summary class="o-faq-accordian__question">
                What is a blank? 
                <div class="o-faq-accordian__icon">
                    <div class="vertical"></div>
                    <div class="horizontal"></div>
                </div></div>

Here's the gist of the SCSS styling:
.o-faq-accordian {

    &:target &__question {
        background-color: $light-gray-background;
    }

    &__question {
        position: relative;
        color: $brand-blue;
    }

   

    &__details &__answer {
        transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    &__details[open] {
        .o-faq-accordian__question:hover {
            .o-faq-accordian__icon {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
     }
}

** I took some of the irrelevant content out of here, so if the end brackets seem off thats why.
I want to add this to the scss file:
&__details {
    box-shadow: #f3f3f4 0px 0px 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

For some reason when I do add the &__details {} to the scss file, the styling will not apply or show on the site and none of it shows in inspection. I'm adding it in just above the &__details &__answer styling. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a simple reason why the styling isn't being accepted?
I was expecting to add in
&__details {
    box-shadow: #f3f3f4 0px 0px 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

and have this pull styling for the class o-faq-accordian__details. However, no styling is pulling under o-faq-accordian__details.

How are you running your build? Are you seeing the expected output in the resulting CSS file?

I'm committing the code through a dev environment in pantheon, and no I'm not seeing the expected output in the CSS!

Ok, but committing code does not necessarily mean that you’re running a build. How exactly are you transpiling your SCSS to CSS?

Thank you for your response! I’ve done some more digging into the build process and the SCSS is being compiled into the theme.css file. I found a corresponding theme.css.map file. However, the styles for .o-faq-accordian__details aren’t appearing in the final theme.css file, but ".o-faq-accordian__details" is there, just none of the styling is.
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer {display: block;}
This displays when inspecting the . Is it possible scss isn't outputting due to being overridden?

Again, you haven't given any information about how you're transpiling SCSS into CSS. This is typically done through an NPM script, Task Runner, Module Bundler, File Watcher, Pipeline, or some kind of external process that handles this. It's not automatic: You need to have something that runs this. If you don't know what that is, then that's probably your issue. You need to find that out.
